# Itemized list in table, creates an unwanted gap

Tags: tables, spacing, lists

I'm trying to add an itemized list in a `tabular` environment, it does work however it adds an unwanted space above the list...

Here's the code...

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% rules
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\section*{Work Experience}

\begin{tabular}{L! {\VRule} R}
2010-2011 & {\bf Profession}\\
& Job Description\\
& \begin{itemize}
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc
\end{itemize} \\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And the result is this...

[image: Table with unwanted gap]

Is there anyway to make the itemized list have less of a line break between its start and 'Job Description'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `paralist`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paralist}

% rules
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\section*{Work Experience}

\begin{tabular}{L! {\VRule} R}
2010-2011 & {\bf Profession}\\
& Job Description\\
& \begin{compactitem}
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc
\end{compactitem} \\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This also eliminates the indentation.[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is grand and the lesser line spacing is ideal for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumitem` and put `topsep=0pt`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\usepackage{titling,enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% rules
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\begin{document}
%
%\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\section*{Work Experience}

\begin{tabular}{L! {\VRule} R}
2010-2011 & {\bf Profession}\\
& Job Description\\
& \begin{itemize}[parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt]
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc
\end{itemize} \\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]